# Serverless I image upload to S3 broken after deploy, local worked only

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, image-upload

I trying to upload an image to S3 uses `serverless` and NodeJS but something wrong after upload. In local uses `serverless-offline` everything worked like champ but after deploy I got this error. Then I tried to intercept and detect what's happened and see this result:

Some strange character appeared in image body such as `<0x0a>` `0x01` `0x04`

[image]

I also tried to use `serverless-apigw-binary` but not luck.

Comment: did you use API gateway in front of your AWS Lambda? How you call the serverless function?

Comment: Yes, and I am using NestJS. Something like `return serverless.proxy(server, event, context);`

Comment: no, what I mean is AWS API Gateway, you will need to allow file type @ AWS API Gateway if you're using it.

Comment: Yes, I am using AWS API Gateway.

Comment: I just found the solution. Thank @xion

Comment: I am facing the same issue and i am also using Nest js with aws-serverless-express, did you find a solution ?

Comment: See my answered below.

Comment: @BinhHo you can mark your self-answer as correct in order to bring more attention to it. (I believe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Self Answer**

Very lucky I just found the solution at
[binary-media-types](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#binary-media-types)

Add this to `serverless.yml`.

```
provider:
  # others
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - '*/*'
```

No need `serverless-apigw-binary`

No need this as well

```
const binaryMimeTypes = [
  'image/gif',
  'image/png',
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/jpg',
];
...

return serverless.createServer(expressApp, null, binaryMimeTypes)
```

Comment: Should I add headers in the request? I am blocked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69810751/image-file-is-not-viewing-uploaded-by-s3  Could you please help me on this

Comment: You can try to debug what happened by `console.log` blob file on API side. Or download uploaded file and check file content/info and see what's happening.

Comment: serverless not supporting this.

Comment: Thank you @BinhHo, serverless config for API Gateway saved me. 
I had set the setting in the UI but it did not take... unless there is somekind of enforcement that I am unaware of. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Following method worked for me.

If want to upload file through lambda, one way is to open your AWS API Gateway console.

Go to

"API" -> {YourAPI} -> "Settings"

There you will find "Binary Media Types" section.

Add following media type:

> multipart/form-data

Save your changes.

Then Go to "Resources" -> "proxy method"(eg. "ANY") -> "Method Request" -> "HTTP Request Headers" and add following headers "Content-Type", "Accept".

Finally deploy your api.

For more info visit: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html

Comment: The best Answer I can see